# How to deploy new firebase functions from an angular project

Tags: angular, firebase

I have an angular project with SSR. It is being hosted as a function in firebase.

I want to keep some firebase functions related to the project here as well.

- I created a new folder in my project for this in `myproject/backend/functions`.
- I navigate my cli into the `myproject/backend/functions` folder
- I run `firebase init firestore`

However the firebase cli detects the firebase setup in the root folder of the project; `myproject`. And it continues to modify that file.

**How should I initialise a folder in my angular project to deploy some firebase functions from inside my project, while also keeping my SSR?**

I am trying to achieve a similar situation as the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: How did you setup you Angular to run with SSR in functions?

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you should have an export for a function so Firebase Function can call it, why wouldn't you add more exports there?

Comment: @Abkarino I used `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` to create an SSR project. You can assume the setup from the official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: @Abkarino The main reason is that I don't want to unnecessarily mix the angular code with the code for cloud functions. Separating the firebase functions would allow me to organise the code better and read and update it much faster. Secondly I don't see how I can deploy functions that listen to firestore events from within express, since that is not route related. Finally I don't always want to deploy all functions with my project.

Comment: I assume you have some setup like this https://i.imgur.com/BmLKLU8.png, right? If yes, then you will make another export for functions.database.ref('/hello').onWrite for example.

Comment: For separation part, I can suggest something but it needs some testing. You can init the firebase function in another folder then move it into your angular. This way, firebase won't check that you have another init in a parent folder. Let me know if that works with you.

Comment: @Abkarino creating the folder outside the angular folder, then moving it worked for me. So far I have seen no unexpected side effects. Leave a formal answer and I will accept it near the end of the bounty period unless a better answers show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Functions supports using web frameworks. Official documentation provides a sample for using `Express` within the functions to handle http requests.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  const date = new Date();
  const hours = (date.getHours() % 12) + 1;  // London is UTC + 1hr;
  res.json({bongs: 'BONG '.repeat(hours)});
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

So, one way to add functions is just to add them after the app export.

```js
exports.helloWatcher =  functions.database.ref('/hello').onWrite(...)
```

Or in case of typescript

```js
export let helloWatcher =  functions.database.ref('/hello').onWrite(...)
```

The OP wanted to have some separation between the Angular SSR project and the rest of the functions.
The issue was that he can't initialize a firebase functions inside another since it detects the parent firebase config.

So the proposed solution was to do the `init` in an external folder, this way `firebase` will create the necessary files. Then move the folder inside the original firebase folder. Since firebase will try to find the config files, it will stop on the first level it finds so it won't check if the config was already nested.

Comment: I used the second approach initialising the folder elsewhere, then moving it.

Comment: I was unable to find the exports in my angular project. Except an exported `app()` in the `server.ts` file, which probably would be exported as firebase functions elsewhere. I was unable to track where the code that moves `app()` to a firebase function resides. It might be inside some library. So that discards the first part of the answer as an option.

Comment: @RobMonhemius https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxCu5TEmxXE this url shows how to start the project, you probably did the same. I didn't share this url since you already have your project initialized, but maybe you want to take a look at that video.